# Groupwise filtering

Tags: r

For each ID I have different dates and I like to filter out for each observation after a specific date. In this example I like to remove all observation for ID 1 after "2020-04-02" and for ID 2 after  "2020-04-03". These specific dates are not included in my data set. Therefor I need a solution where I can type them in manually.

Exempel:

```
test <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(c('1', '1', '1', '1', 
                                    '1', '1', '2', '2',
                                    '2', '2')),
                   date = as.POSIXct(c('2020-03-31', '2020-04-01', 
                                       '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', 
                                       '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04',
                                       '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03',
                                       '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05')))
```

Expected output:

```
  ID       date
1  1 2020-03-31
2  1 2020-04-01
3  1 2020-04-02
4  2 2020-04-02
5  2 2020-04-03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a reference dataset to filter the dates, join the data and remove the dates.

```
remove_date <- data.frame(ID = factor(1:2), 
                          remove_date = as.Date(c("2020-04-02", "2020-04-03")))

subset(merge(test, remove_date, by = 'ID'), date <= remove_date)
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  inner_join(remove_date, by = 'ID') %>%
  filter(date <= remove_date)

#  ID       date remove_date
#1  1 2020-03-31  2020-04-02
#2  1 2020-04-01  2020-04-02
#3  1 2020-04-02  2020-04-02
#4  2 2020-04-02  2020-04-03
#5  2 2020-04-03  2020-04-03
```

**data**

```
test <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(c('1', '1', '1', '1', 
                                    '1', '1', '2', '2',
                                    '2', '2')),
                   date = as.Date(c('2020-03-31', '2020-04-01', 
                                       '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', 
                                       '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04',
                                       '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03',
                                       '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05')))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
test.filter <- data.table(ID = as.factor(1:2), 
                          date.max = as.POSIXct(c('2020-04-02', '2020-04-03')))
setDT(test)
test.filter[test, .(ID, date), on = .(ID, date.max >= date ), nomatch = 0L]
#    ID       date
# 1:  1 2020-03-31
# 2:  1 2020-04-01
# 3:  1 2020-04-02
# 4:  2 2020-04-02
# 5:  2 2020-04-03
```